# TUD theme - Title of beamer presentation runs outside the screen

Tags: beamer, line-breaking, titles

the title does not continue on a second line but runs outside the screen

[image: Title page]

Different .sty files are used but i'm not sure where the problem is located. The main .tex files is as follows

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{tud}}
\title[Master thesis defence]
{The influence of the leading edge thickness on the force coefficients for airfoils at $90^\circ$ angle of attack}
%\subtitle
%\institute[TU Delft]{Delft University of Technology}
\author{M. Van Roosbroeck}
\date{\today}

% Insert frame before each subsection (requires 2 latex runs)
\AtBeginSubsection[] {
    \begin{frame}<beamer>\frametitle{\titleSubsec}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]  % Generation of the Table of Contents
    \end{frame}
}
% Define the title of each inserted pre-subsection frame
\newcommand*\titleSubsec{Outline}
% Define the title of the "Table of Contents" frame
\newcommand*\titleTOC{Outline}

% define a symbol which can be removed if you don't need it
\newcommand{\field}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\Zset}{\field{Z}}

\begin{document}

{
% remove the next line if you don't want a background image
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{images/background-titlepage.jpg}}%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\usebeamertemplate*{minimal footline}}
\frame{\titlepage}
}
```

I think the problem is located in the following peace of code which is in an .sty file :

```
\DeclareOptionBeamer{shadow}[true]{\def\beamer@themerounded@shadow{#1}}
\ExecuteOptionsBeamer{shadow=false}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\mode<presentation>

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{}{
    \newsavebox\titleBox
    \newsavebox\subtitleBox
    \newsavebox\instituteBox
    \newsavebox\authorBox
    \newsavebox\dateBox
    \sbox{\titleBox}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle}
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
        \sbox{\subtitleBox}{}
    \else%
        \sbox{\subtitleBox}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\insertsubtitle}
    \fi%
    \sbox{\instituteBox}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute}\usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute}
    \sbox{\authorBox}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor}
    \sbox{\dateBox}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{date}\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate}
    \newlength{\titleBoxWidth}
    \newlength{\titleBoxInnerWidth}
    \setlength{\titleBoxInnerWidth}{\maxof{\wd\titleBox}{\maxof{\wd\subtitleBox}{\maxof{\wd\instituteBox}{\maxof{\wd\authorBox}{\wd\dateBox}}}}}
    \setlength{\titleBoxWidth}{\titleBoxInnerWidth}
    \addtolength{\titleBoxWidth}{1cm}

    \begin{textblock*}{\titleBoxWidth}(0.5cm,2.5cm)
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=2mm,leftskip=3mm,rightskip=3mm,wd=\titleBoxWidth,center]{title block body}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0pt,vmode,wd=\titleBoxInnerWidth,left]{}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\wd\titleBox]{title}
            \usebox{\titleBox}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
        \else%
            \vskip1mm
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\wd\subtitleBox]{subtitle}
                \usebox{\subtitleBox}%
            \end{beamercolorbox}
        \fi%
        \vskip1mm
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\wd\instituteBox]{institute}
            \usebox{\instituteBox}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vskip7mm
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\wd\authorBox]{author}
            \usebox{\authorBox}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vskip1mm
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\wd\dateBox]{date}
            \usebox{\dateBox}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vskip0pt
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{textblock*}
}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\hspace*{0.5cm}}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[circle]

\mode
<all>
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Many Thanks

The following solution is suggested:

Replace the the line with `\sbox{\titleBox}{...}` with

```
\sbox\titleBox{\parbox{\linewidth}{%           
   \usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle}}
```

which has as a consequence an error in the compilation referring to: `\useinnertheme[shadow]{tux}`

deactivating this line results in a successful compilation but has alternative output

[image]

how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Instead of editing Herbert's answer, you should comment on it or edit your original question to include the additional information.

Comment: in the comment box i can not add picture or code lines i guess?

Answer (score 7):

Replace the the line with `\sbox{\titleBox}{...}` with

```
\sbox\titleBox{\parbox{\linewidth}{%       
   \usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle}}
```

and it will work.

Comment: A error has shown up during compilation. Deactivating the line results a successful compilation but an output which is different then intended. (See question)

Comment: then provide your theme `tud` fro a download to test it.

Comment: Can i send you somehow the zip file with the template i use so you can have a look?

Comment: send it to `hvoss@tug.org`

Answer (score 4):

With a `minipage` around the title, you get the desired results, just replace

```
  \usebox{\titleBox}%
```

by

```
  \begin{minipage}[b][24mm][b]{110mm} % <- adjust width or position here!!!
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\usebeamerfont{title}{\inserttitle\par}
  \end{minipage}
```

[image]

The complete changed `beamerinnerthemetud.sty` (originally from http://www.ewi.tudelft.nl/en/the-faculty/departments/applied-mathematics/latex/beamer/):

```
% TU Delft Beamer template
% Author: Maarten Abbink
% Delft Universiy of Technology
% March 2014
\DeclareOptionBeamer{shadow}[true]{\def\beamer@themerounded@shadow{#1}}
\ExecuteOptionsBeamer{shadow=false}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\mode<presentation>

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{}{
    \newsavebox\titleBox
    \newsavebox\subtitleBox
    \newsavebox\instituteBox
    \newsavebox\authorBox
    \newsavebox\dateBox
    \sbox{\titleBox}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle}
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
        \sbox{\subtitleBox}{}
    \else%
        \sbox{\subtitleBox}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\insertsubtitle}
    \fi%
    \sbox{\instituteBox}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute}\usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute}
    \sbox{\authorBox}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor}
    \sbox{\dateBox}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{date}\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate}
    \newlength{\titleBoxWidth}
    \newlength{\titleBoxInnerWidth}
    \setlength{\titleBoxInnerWidth}{\maxof{\wd\titleBox}{\maxof{\wd\subtitleBox}{\maxof{\wd\instituteBox}{\maxof{\wd\authorBox}{\wd\dateBox}}}}}
    \setlength{\titleBoxWidth}{\titleBoxInnerWidth}
    \addtolength{\titleBoxWidth}{1cm}

    \begin{textblock*}{\titleBoxWidth}(0.5cm,2.5cm)
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=2mm,leftskip=3mm,rightskip=3mm,wd=\titleBoxWidth,center]{title block body}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0pt,vmode,wd=\titleBoxInnerWidth,left]{}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\wd\titleBox]{title}
      \begin{minipage}[b][24mm][b]{110mm} % <- adjust width or position here!!!
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\usebeamerfont{title}{\inserttitle\par}
      \end{minipage}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
        \else%
            \vskip1mm
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\wd\subtitleBox]{subtitle}
                \usebox{\subtitleBox}%
            \end{beamercolorbox}
        \fi%
        \vskip1mm
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\wd\instituteBox]{institute}
            \usebox{\instituteBox}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vskip7mm
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\wd\authorBox]{author}
            \usebox{\authorBox}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vskip1mm
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\wd\dateBox]{date}
            \usebox{\dateBox}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vskip0pt
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{textblock*}
}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\hspace*{0.5cm}}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[circle]

\mode
<all>
```

Comment: that doesn't change anything

Comment: see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same template with a long title as well -- I fixed it by going into the sty. file with the name "beamerfontthemetud.sty" and changed the title and the subtitle formatting so that they were the same thing (illusion of title being split into 2) -- this also keeps the integrity of the black box!

See changes below (I've marked the parts I've changed):

```
% TU Delft Beamer template
% Author: Maarten Abbink
% Delft Universiy of Technology
% March 2014
\mode<presentation>

\setbeamerfont{normal text}{family=\sffamily}

\setbeamerfont{structure}{family=\rmfamily}
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries,size=\Large}    % FIXED
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{series=\bfseries,size=\Large} % FIXED
\setbeamerfont{institute}{parent=structure,series=\bfseries,size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{date}{parent=author}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}

\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{parent=structure,family=\sffamily}

\setbeamerfont{block body}{parent=normal text}

\setbeamerfont{item}{parent=normal text}

\mode
```